# prevent ampersand getting converted to &amp;

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring MVC webapp (not sure if that info matters but it might be) that passes a string value to the JSP file using ModelAndView.

The string value is in the form:

```
&#100;&#64;&#46;&#110;&#121;
```

When the tomcat displays the resulting HTML, all ampersands have been converted to:

```
&amp;#99;&amp;#97;
```

which is not what I want. I've tried some escape functions from Apache commons and Spring but they produce weird output:

```
&amp;amp;#99;&amp;amp;#97;
```

Any ideas on how to prevent this? thanks :)

Comment: Have you checked out [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)?

Comment: I was looking at URLEncode for a different reason yesterday or the day before but when I tried "UTF-8" on the encoding scheme, eclipse won't compile my code. I've search for other possible values but can't find it.

Comment: just tried "ISO-8859-1" encoding but not working

Comment: What is the expected output? Is it `&c&a`?

Comment: expected output on my browser is ca without the ampersands. from what I recall: &#99 = c

Comment: is escapexml=false available?

Comment: available where? please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the string is already escaped (per HTML rules), just output it raw; this should work

```
 <%= string %>
```

but if you output it some other way, an additional escaping may be applied.

The deeper problem is, why has the lower layer escaped the string? It shouldn't.

Comment: I'm current displaying my variable using ${myVariable}. I changed it to your suggestion and I got an error that says "myVariable cannot be resolved to a variable."

Comment: @mrjayviper: use <%=request.getAttribute('myVariable')%> instead